# Save custom column value in database using component in joomla JModelAdmin

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla and working on one component. I want to create an additional column in database. For that I have created column in database table. And also added it in html form. But in controllers function save doesn't save. I have tried like this

```
$validData = $model->validate($form, $data);
$validData["ratehr"] = 45;
if (!$model->save($validData)) {......
```

"ratehr" is new column in database table. But this didn't save "ratehr" value in table rest all values saved successfully.
What I am missing or need to add code in somewhere else.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check administrator/tables/"yourtableclass". In this class you have to assign this new column.